# Go-Ethereum: Are storage trie storage slots hashed twice?

Tags: go-ethereum, storage-trie

The GetState method in the stateObject class expects a `common.Hash` argument, a storage slot that is the hash of all parameters in it. That is all well so far.

```
func (s *stateObject) GetState(key common.Hash) common.Hash {
```

Then, GetState calls GetStorage (assuming we are fetching from the database and not from caches). And, GetStorage is... hashing the key again.

```
func (t *StateTrie) GetStorage(_ common.Address, key []byte) ([]byte, error) {
    enc, err := t.trie.Get(t.hashKey(key))
    if err != nil || len(enc) == 0 {
        return nil, err
    }
    _, content, _, err := rlp.Split(enc)
    return content, err
}
```

This is counter-intuititve to me, as hashing a second time adds nothing in terms of randomness. Are storage slots in storage tries hashed twice or am I misreading this?

**Edit:**

Have figured out now that they are not hashed twice. I assumed "key" parameter to `GetState` was always already hashed. But it isn't. It sometimes is but not always. For basic storage slots, it is not a hash but just `[]byte{0}`, `[]byte{1}`, `[]byte{2}`, etc, padded to 32 byte. And in some other cases it is also non-random, such as for iterating through an array. Was able to figure this out by using Remix debugger and testing to see the storage slot keys and object hashes.